# Why Spring automatically casts mongoDB object to Base class type

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-jpa

I have a java entity class as

```
@Document(collection = "ftabcd")
class FTABCD{
@Id
String id

List<Base> baseList;

}

class Base {
String a;String b;
}

@TypeAlias("existingchild1name")
class child1 extends Base {
 String child1refNO;
}

@TypeAlias("existingchild2name")
class child2 extends Base {
 String child2refNO;
}
```

So now, in database we have an entry like this

```
{
"_id":ObjectId("5323465645431235465"),
"baseList": [
      {
    "child1refNo":"child1value",
    "a":"avalue", 
    "b":"bvalue",
    "_class":"existingchild1name"
      }
            ]
}
```

so when I do ,

*FTABCDRepository.findById(5323465645431235465);*

the object that I get from db reads "baseList"  as  List and the each element of the list is converted to Base class ,

baseList=[Base(a="avalue", b="bvalue")]

although it could have been  converted to Child1 or Child2.
How can I make it to read the same as Child1 type or Child2 type and have child1refNo or child2refNo associated to it.

**Expected Result Should be
baseList=[child1(child1refNo = "child1value",a="avalue", b="bvalue")]**